# Finding the maximum and minimum points of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Consider the function $f(x, y) =\sqrt{xy}$ on the domain:
$$D =\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 ≤ 5, x ≥ 0, y ≥ 0\}$$
In terms of finding the minimum point, I calculated the derivative of the function and made the derivative equal to $0.$ The outcome was that $x=0$ and $y=0$ (global min).

However, what's the approach to calculating the maximum point?

Comment: It is be on the boundary, Parameterize  the boundary, and optimize on this parameter.  As for the minimum.  All along the x axis and the y axis (including the origin) $f(x,y) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $D$ is a compact set, the function achieves its maximum and minimum, and it is or in a critical point, or at the boundary of the region.

So besides critical points, one has to do a search independently on the lines/curves
 $x=0,$  $y=0$,  $x^2+y^2=5$ (this latest with the change of coordinates to polar coordinates, or with the use of Lagrange multipliers), and compare the values with
 $f(0,0), f(0,\sqrt 5), f(\sqrt 5,0).$
The largest is the global maximum of $f$ on $D.$

Comment: is it possible for the maximum point and minimum point to be the same? since the values of f(0,0), f(0,√5) and f(√5,0) are the same (none are larger than the other, so no global max?)

Comment: Here $0$ is a minimum (all  values $f(x,y)$ are nonnegative and $0$ is obtained for each point of the segment $x=0$ or $y=0$). The maximum, if I am not wrong, is obtained at the middle point of the arc $f(\sqrt {5 /2}, \sqrt {5/2})=\sqrt {5/2}.$

Comment: Be careful - the derivatives don't exist at  any of the points where $f$ achieves its minimum $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\geq \frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$$